# Angular 6 - build with assets not found

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I'm trying to create a build of my angular's project.
I'm using scss with assets like this:

```
.ciao {
  background-image: url("../../assets/images/bck--registration-company.png");
}
```

running this code:

```
ng build --prod --configuration=coll --base-href ./
```

I have inside dist folder, in the same directory of index.html, the file "bck--registration-company.png" and the "assets" folder where inside there is another "bck--registration-company.png". I would like to use resources inside assets folder.

I've tried to change base href, relative and absolute image path but nothing.
example:

```
.background--image-carousel2{
  background-image: url("/assets/images/carousel2.jpg");
}
```

with this path the REQUEST URL) is :

```
Request URL: http://localhost:63342/assets/images/carousel2.jpg
```

this is wrong because it could be:

```
http://localhost:63342/project/dist/name_project/assets/images/bck--registration-company.png
```

in my angular.json:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/name_project",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [

        ]
      },
```

How could I resolve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Try this `url("./assets/images/carousel2.jpg");`

Comment: same here, error: NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError

Answer (score 5):

Try this way

Angular is able to access directly **assets** folder.

```
.ciao {
   background-image: url("assets/images/bck--registration-company.png");
}
```

Then make a build

```
ng build --prod
```

Then put the whole system path in dist/index.html file

In base url set the whole path of the project folder.

Comment: i've a error in build time: 
`ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

  background-image: url(assets/images/bck--registration-company.png");
                                                              ^
      Invalid CSS after "...tration-company": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was '.png");'
      in C:\Users\t.ruscica\workspace\ws_svn_agos\project\project_name\src\app\landing\landing.component.scss (line 3, column 64)`

Comment: Try with `background-image: url(./assets...`

Comment: NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError.